# How do I use Cypress Origin with google accounts?

Tags: javascript, cypress, cross-domain

I am attempting to access a google service embedded into my website which uses accounts.google.com for the login.

I'm trying to use the session/origin commands to do this, but it's failing as if I'm doing nothing at all.  I use this with success to login to my application (non google login), but google seems to require something more.  I have spent a great deal of time browsing for answers with no luck

Code leading up to login:

```
cy.get('div [class="active carousel-item"]').find('button').first().click()
cy.loginGoogle(Cypress.env("GoogleUsername"),Cypress.env("GooglePassword"))
```

Login code:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('loginGoogle', (username, password) => {
const args = { username, password }

cy.session(args, () =>

{
 cy.origin('https://accounts.google.com', { args }, ({ username, password }) => {
  cy.visit('https://accounts.google.com/')
  cy.get('input[type="email"]').type(username)
  cy.get('div[id="identifierNext"]').find('button').click()
  cy.get('#login-password').type(password)
  cy.get('#btn-login').click()
})
cy.visit('/')
cy.url().should('contain', 'mydomain.com')
})
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use programmatic authentication as it's suggested in the [documentation.](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/end-to-end-testing/google-authentication#What-you-ll-learn)

Comment: Thanks.  There are several ways of getting around the issue, but it doesn't deal with my employers desire to do it all via the UI.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please don't share only links as answers, but summarize the content a little and show how it contributes to the solution.